# Drupal Composite Image Field

Tags: drupal-8

I have a drupal site where I want to show some videos.

I would like to have a field where I can Uplaod  and Image, a title, a description, and url for video.

I could not figure it out how could I make this. I believe drupal has some way of doing custom fieds.

Is it possible to do the above?

Comment: If you don't want to create your module, there are tutorials for this online. It's a basic thing actually. Like [this](https://www.drupal.org/forum/general/show-off-your-drupal-site/2014-01-02/how-to-make-embed-video-gallery-using-views-and).
Also, you could have a look at [video module](https://www.drupal.org/project/video).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did with a paragraph type where I put all the fields I need it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same goal, but I don't want to use Paragraph for this. I created a fieldItem, a fieldWidget and a fieldFormatter.
For the image subfield, in my fieldItem class I use an integer type :

```
$properties['poster'] = DataDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('Poster override'))
```

and inside the widget class, I use a 'managed_file' type :

```
$element['poster'] = array(
      '#title' => $this->t('The poster of the video'),
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#upload_location' => 'private://',
...)
```

It works fine, but my problem is that I want the upload widget to work as well as a "classic image field", that is to say with a preview of the uploaded image, and so on.

Do you think it is possible ?

Thanks
ben